# Using ligatures font in Google Docs?

Tags: fonts, google-docs, ligature

Is it possibile to use ligature fonts ([like Fire code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)) in a Google Docs Document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible u just have to click the font menu, and at the top there should be More fonts Button.

In there you can search for more fonts, Fire Code should be present as well as Fire Mono which is the same font but without ligature.

Comment: Finally got a font for my homework, thanks!

Comment: For some reason there is a bug where all litagure characters need to be re-typed if you are switching the font of an existing document. At first I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working until I figured this out.